# How to enable users to copy text from textarea, on a button click?

Tags: javascript, php

I dont want the text to be copied from one textarea to another, I just want that the content should only get copied and the user then could paste it anywhere he wants, using ctrl+v or paste option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CSS**

```
*.unselectable {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none
}
```

**HTML**

```
<textarea unselectable="on" id="my_textarea"></textarea>
<input type="button" id="btnCopy" value="Copy" />
```

You can use [zclip](http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/) for copy text to clipboard.

```
$("#btnCopy").zclip({
    path: "js/ZeroClipboard.swf",
    copy: function(){
        return $("#my_textarea").val();
    }
});
```